# "prisma migrate dev" on existing database

Tags: javascript, prisma

im trying to setup prisma migrate on a database (mysql) already populated with data on my dev enviroment but so far i can't make it work.

**1.**
I did `prisma db pull` to create the schema from it (works fine).
When running `prisma migrate dev --name initial-migration --create-only` i get a warning asking to RESET the database... i dont want that. So...

**2.**
Run this command `prisma migrate diff --from-empty --to-schema-datamodel prisma/schema.prisma --script > migration.sql` and manually move the sql file to a manually created prisma/migrations/init folder

**3.**
Now i try to baseline that migration running `prisma migrate resolve --applied "initial"`

i get an error saying the migration cant be found.. but it's there and even prisma knows it.,..

[console capture of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLBbM.jpg)

Comment: I am having similar issue did you manage to resolve it ?

Comment: @KishanOza no, this is still an opened issue: https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/14762